# AggregatedException - Access properties of inner exception where type extends exception

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a method which catches `AggregateException`'s. However, I can't seem to access properties on the inner exceptions that were added to exceptions that inherit the base `Exception`.

For example, the type `Azure.RequestFailedException` contains a property `ErrorCode`. Using the code below, I am not able to access that property when handling an `AggregatedException` because `ex` is always of type `Exception`.

```
Console.WriteLine(ex.ErrorCode);
```

> 'Exception' does not contain a definition for 'ErrorCode'...

How can I access these properties when the exception is part of an `AggregatedException`?

```
public Response GetBin(string binName)
{
    try
    {
        BlobContainerClient container = this._storage.GetContainer(binName);
        Azure.AsyncPageable<BlobItem> blobs = this._storage.GetBlobs(container);
        return new GetBinResponse(container, blobs);
    }
    catch (AggregateException ae)
    {
        Response exResponse = null;
        ae.Handle(ex =>
        {
            if (ex is Azure.RequestFailedException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ErrorCode);
                exResponse = new BinNotFoundExceptionResponse(binName);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                exResponse = new BadRequestResponse(ex.Message);
                return true;
            }
        });
        return exResponse;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new BadRequestResponse(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: probably you need to cast to the specific type, e.g. `if(ex is WhateverType e) Console.WriteLine(e.ErrorCode)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not **convert to** but only **check for** the type. Use this instead:

```
if (ex is Azure.RequestFailedException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ErrorCode)
}
```

Or before pattern-matching, which was introduced in C#7:

```
var e = ex as Azure.RequestFailedException;
if (e != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ErrorCode)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed. Much simpler than I'd expected!